# Ajax - Post with ISA Authentication from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

Our web service is behind an ISA server which is used for users to enter their windows credentials for authentication.
I would like to call the web service from JavaScript.

I am using the following script but am not able to capture the authentication cookie.  Within the success/error or complete methods the status is always 0 and according to fiddler the return value is 302

I have logged in manually and i constructed the same post via ajax but i am not able to complete the call with any success.  Status is always 0 and error is thrown but with 'error' text.

What would i be doing wrong? Is this possible?

```
    function go(){
        var url = 'https://domain.com/CookieAuth.dll?Logon';

    var formData = {            
        curl: "Z2F",
        flags: 0,
        forcedownlevel: 0,
        formdir: 6,
        trusted: 0,         
        username: "domain\\username",
        password: "password",
        SubmitCreds: 'Log On'
    }; 
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: "POST",
        crossdomain: true,
        headers:{
            Accept: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
        },
        data: formData,
        contentType:" application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            var cookie = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie'); //cookie is always null

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            var cookie = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie'); //always null
            alert('error:' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
        },
        complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 302) { //status is always 0
            }
            var cookie = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie'); //Set-Cookie
            alert(jqXHR.status);
        }
    });

    $('#mydiv').html('hello');
};
```